# Reading Link in Address Bar GTM

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager

I have already installed Outbound Link tag on Google Tag Manager, but I was wondering if it is possible for Google Tag Manager to read what the visitor writes in their address bar, or if they go to a bookmarked link.

I can't find much infomation on it, and wondering if it is even possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. (Plus it ll be a total violation to the user privacy)